# how to convert rows int columns in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

In the following query have three table join i.e. `ration_card_and_member_count_orignal_tp`, `commodityallotment` and `AllotmentSchedules`. this query returns data according fps ,districtcode and card type. I want to convert query result from row to column

```
Select  
    a.qty, a.commodity,   
    c.rationcardcount, c.district_code, c.fps_id,
    a.qty * c.rationcardcount totalquantity,
    c.card_type, d.AllotmentType 
from
    (select  
         sum(rccount) rationcardcount, district_code,
         fps_id, card_type  
     from 
         [ration_card_and_member_count_orignal_tp] 
     where 
         card_type in (01, 02, 03) 
         and district_code = 033  
         and fps_id = 2668 
     group by 
         fps_id, card_type, district_code) c,
    CommodityAllotments a
inner join
    AllotmentSchedules d on a.Allotment_Schedule_id = d.Schedule_id 
where 
    d.AllotmentType = 1 
    and a.card_type_id in (01, 02, 03)   
    and (2016 between cast(Allotment_From_Year as int) and cast(Allotment_To_Year as int)) 
    and (2016 between cast(Allotment_From_Year as int) and cast(Allotment_To_Year as int)) 
    and (2 between cast(Allotment_From_Month as int) and Allotment_To_Month as int))
    and (2 between cast(Allotment_From_Month as int) and cast(Allotment_To_Month as int))
```

Above query return the data in following format:

```
qty     commodity   rationcardcount district_code   fps_id  totalquantity       card_type   AllotmentType
15      Rice        258             033             2668     3870                 01        1
15      Rice        2               033             2668     30                   02        1
15      Rice        53              033             2668     795                   03       1
20      Wheat       258             033             2668     5160                  01       1
20      Wheat       2               033              2668     40                   02       1
20      Wheat        53             033              2668     1060                 03       1
```

I want to display data in following format:

```
  qty   commodity    district_code   fps_id    01      02    03

   15   Rice         033             2668    3870    30    795

   20   Wheat        033             2668    5160    40    1060
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivot function should do the trick,

```
SELECT [qty],[commodity],[district_code],[fpd_id],[01],[02],[03]
FROM   [dbo].<YOUR_TABLENAME>
PIVOT
(
       SUM(totalquantity)
       FOR [card_type] IN ([01],[02],[03])
) AS P
```